# Break words on tag boundaries with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse html to text with BeautifulSoup but I have a problem: some words are divided by tags with no spaces:

```
<span>word1</span><span>word2</space>
```

So when I extract the text I have:

```
word1word2
```

Some sentences are also joined to one sentence:

```
INTODUCTION There are many...
```

Is there a simple way to force word separation on tags with BeautifulSoup? Also may be I can fix sentence separation on some tags?

I have several complicated html files. I process them to text like:

```
plain_texts = [BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").get_text() for html in htmls]
```

Comment: how are you getting text from html tag? with `.text`?

Comment: @Upasana Mittal  BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").get_text()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>words</title></head><body><span>word1</span><span>word2</span></body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(span.text)
```

Which prints the text between the `<span>` tags seperately:

```
word1
word2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tinker with your soup using `replace_with()` method ([docs here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)). But lot depends on structure of your HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<html><body><span>word1</span><span>word2</space>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
for span in soup.select('span'):
    span.replace_with(span.text + ' ')

print(soup.text.strip())
```

This prints:

```
word1 word2
```